# Maximum connected Accounts in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, user-accounts, service-accounts

we are using a iam.gserviceaccount.com Email adresss to connect our tool with the Google Analytics accounts from our clients. 
We have reached the maximum connected accounts, but an upgrade is not possible because we can't response to the emails sent by analytics support.
Is there another way to upgrade it? Or is there another possibility to connect our tool with the analytics API?

We already tried to upgrade the account with the analytics support, but it is not working because of the emailadress.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by maximum connected accounts?

Comment: We are using the E-Mail Adress for Analytics and for the api to integrate the data from our clients in our Tool. Now we can‘t connect any more Analytics Accounts with this E-Mail because we already have 100 connected Accounts. And we can’t Upgrade it because it is a Service Account E-Mail.

Answer (score 1):

For normal Google analytics accounts there is a limit to 100 accounts that you can have access to.  If you upgraded to a premium account if i remember correctly that number jumps to 250.

You are currently using a service account and granting it access to a number of Google analytics accounts.  The service account is going to be bound by the normal user limit of 100 and your not going to be able to increase that.

The problem is that you are using service accounts in correctly. Your not supposed to be giving the service account out to your customers and asking them to add it as a user on their Google analytics account.  Service accounts are intended to be used by developers and companies that have access to data and want to share that data with others.

You should be using Oauth2 to gain access to the users data and saving the refresh token in your application which will enable you to request data for the user when ever needed.

By using a service account you are going to be hit with a lot of quota limits because they are shared by the user a user can only make so many requests so fast per day.   By using Oauth2 you would be using different users and would not have as many issues with the user based quotas.